# Is there any method to truncate date, so that it remains using index by date

Tags: oracle, indexing, plsql, oracle11g, truncate

I have a huge table that has index by date. By using the index I am getting data, no problem. But I have to trunc(date) to month, so that it includes whole month, by doing this I am losing access by index. Is there any way?thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't want to leave question unanswered, I've solved this by using method `LAST_DAY(:edate)+1-1/86400` 
and `ADD_MONTHS((LAST_DAY(:edate)+1),-1)`

AND YES, I tried to find method to avoid `TRUNC()`

Answer (score 2):

You will have to avoid any transformation on your date column.
You can do that for example with a clause like this (this example gives all rows for this month) :

`And (mydatecol >= trunc(sysdate,'MM') and mydatecol < trunc(add_month(sysdate,+1),'MM') )`

Just transform your variable and don't touch the column.

Comment: to be a little more meticulous, the clause `And mydatecol between trunc(sysdate,'MM') and trunc(add_month(sysdate,+1),'MM')` can also return rows for 1st of may at 00:00. You'd better use ">=" and "<" like I edited.